# sqlalchemy: How can I associate object of other table with primary key?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a `Transaction` table as

```
class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    amount = Column('amount', Float)
    category_id = Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    date_created = Column('date_created', Date, default=datetime.now())
    date_modified = Column('date_modifed', Date, onupdate=datetime.now())
```

and `Category` table as

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    subtype = Column('subtype', String)
```

I add the transaction dataset as

```
name, amount, category_id
Costo,59.0,5
Costo,20,5
Safeway,6.75,1
Safeway,11,1
Safeway,19,1
```

and I can see them as well when I query them

```
for transaction in session.query(Transaction):
    logging.info(transaction)
```

and I see the data as well

```
INFO:root:<Transaction(22, Medical Insurance, 110.0, 62, 2013-03-09, None)>
INFO:root:<Transaction(23, AllState Renter Insurance, 100.0, 77, 2013-03-09, None)>
```

But I do see the `categoty_id` as **62** and **77**.

All I need the their values as objects like

```
INFO:root:<Transaction(22, Medical Insurance, 110.0, **Medical**, 2013-03-09, None)>
INFO:root:<Transaction(23, AllState Renter Insurance, 100.0, **Insurance**, 2013-03-09, None)>
```

How can I attach the objects of different table?

I am sure just using `primary_key` will not suffice, but what else I need to do?
Please advice

I have just started learning about `SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create a `relationship()`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    subtype = Column('subtype', String)
    # This line is new
    transactions = relationship("Transaction", backref="category")
```

I'm not sure if I entirely understood your question, but this should attach a `transactions` attribute to each category containing a collection of associated items. Or alternatively:

```
class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    amount = Column('amount', Float)
    category_id = Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    date_created = Column('date_created', Date, default=datetime.now())
    date_modified = Column('date_modifed', Date, onupdate=datetime.now())
    category = relationship("category")
```

to attach objects many-to-one in the opposite direction (as @daydreamer already figured out).

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following line in my `Transaction`, I was able to refer to the `Category` associated with the transaction

```
category = relationship('Category')
```

My class `Transaction` finally looks like

```
class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
    amount = Column('amount', Float)
    category_id = Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    date_created = Column('date_created', Date, default=datetime.now())
    date_modified = Column('date_modifed', Date, onupdate=datetime.now())
    category = relationship('Category')
```

and I can see the output as

```
INFO:root:<Transaction(28, ATT, 89.0, <Category(148, Utilities, Phone)>, 2013-03-09, None)>
INFO:root:<Transaction(27, Car Gas, 47.0, <Category(146, Utilities, Gas & Fuel)>, 2013-03-09, None)>
```

Thanks to @David Marx for pointing to the right documentation

Comment: Glad to help. Hold on to that page, you will probably need to reference it frequently if you're learning SQLalchemy.